# Descending FC series

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, nilpotent-groups

In analogy to the [central series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_series) one can define a FC series as a sequence $A_i$ of normal subgroups such that 
$$
\{1\} = A_0 \lhd A_1 \lhd A_2 \lhd \cdots \lhd A_n = G
$$
such that $A_{i+1}/ A_i$ is contained in $Z_{FC}(G/A_i)$ where $Z_{FC}$ is the FC-centre (the characteristic subgroups given by elements who have finite conjugacy classes).

The prototypical example would be the **ascending** FC series where $A_{i+1}$ is the normal subgroup such that $A_{i+1}/A_i = Z_{FC}(G/A_i)$.

**Question:** is there a iterative procedure to define a **descending** FC series?

Here are some of the desirable properties for this descending series (note that these properties are just stated in analogy with those of the descending central series):

- be defined in terms of a reasonably "natural" groups (the descending central series is given by commutators which are very special subgroups; the ascending FC series is defined by characteristic subgroups which are maximal for this purpose).
- terminate in finitely many steps when the groups is virtually nilpotent (the ascending FC series already does this)
- coincide with the descending central series in the case of matrix groups (with 1 on the diagonals and integer entries above the diagonal)
- have the same length as the ascending FC series when the group is virtually nilpotent

A candidate I looked at is $D_0 = G$ and $D_{i+1}$ is the "smallest" normal subgroup such that one gets a FC series, but I could not find any reason for "smallest" to be well-defined.

EDIT: just to make things clear, I don't believe one can find a procedure with all those properties. But even a procedure with the first two properties would be interesting.

Comment: Probably not. Indeed the first quotient of such a series ought to be the largest FC-central quotient of $G$. But there's usually no such quotient. For instance in a residually finite group, it should be a quotient of which every finite quotient is a quotient, so would be the whole group, but this is usually not a FC-central group.

Comment: Agreed, the naive strategy is going to fail. But this does not mean that there are no alternative possibilities.

Comment: In any case this implies that there is no such series that is compatible with taking quotients (like the lower central series, derived series, etc).